# Java generics with wildcards and static wrappers

Tags: java, generics

Excuse me about so generic question title, but was not sure how to call my question properly.

See the default types of result of `Collections.singleton` calls:

```
Set<Number> numberSingleton = 
    Collections.singleton((Number) null);

Set<Collection> rawCollectionSingleton = 
    Collections.singleton((Collection) null);

Set<Collection<String>> stringCollectionSingleton = 
    Collections.singleton((Collection<String>) null);

Set<? extends Collection<?>> anyCollectionSingleton = 
    Collections.singleton((Collection<?>) null);
```

What I can't explain is the last line. Why `? extends Collection<?>` is used instead of simple `Collection<?>`?

Is this a correct fix for this?

```
Set<Collection<?>> anyCollectionSingleton = 
    Collections.<Collection<?>>singleton((Collection<?>) null);
```

**Why I started all this:**

I had an issue with not compiling line:

```
java.util.Optional.ofNullable((Collection<?>) a).orElse((Collection<?>) b);
```

This seems to fix the issue, but what is the price?

```
java.util.Optional.<Collection<?>>ofNullable((Collection<?>) a).orElse((Collection<?>) b);
```

Comment: Your question is about why IDE generates that strange type? Because Set<Collection<?>> singleton = Collections.singleton((Collection<?>) null); works fine

Comment: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_40 gives me compilation error `java: incompatible types: java.util.Set<java.util.Collection<capture#1 of ?>> cannot be converted to java.util.Set<java.util.Collection<?>>`. What Java version do you use?

Comment: Interesting. Doing `javac` directly through command line using 1.8.0_40 doesn't report any error. Still compilation with IBM JDK 1.6_sr9 does fail with ` incompatible types` error.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a completely different concept.

What is meant to be used with

```
Set<? extends Collection<?>> anyCollectionSingleton = 
Collections.singleton((Collection<?>) null);
```

is that you have a generic class that extends a Collection of generic classes.

So, it's about inheritance.

Comment: But why doesn't case with `Collection<String>` behave the same?

Comment: In general, `String` in something like an independent class, as it directly inherits from `Object` class, whereas for example the `Integer` class inherits from `Number`. Is this enough for your case? If you meant something else, an example could be helpful.

Comment: I meant why `Collection<String>` produces `Set<Collection<String>>` and not `Set<? extends Collection<String>>` then like in the `Collection<?>` case?

Comment: Because the `String` class isn't connected with any inheritance relation with any other Java classes, except from the obvious one, the `Object` class, from which all classes inherit. That is, there isn't any class that `String` extends (I'm not counting the obvious one -> `Object`) and because a definition like `String extends Object` is obvious from the language/compiler itself, it is just skipped.

Comment: I'm still not getting your point. Let's replace the `String` example with generic type `T` (e.g. defined in method). The result will still be `Set<Collection<T>>` and not `Set<? extends Collection<T>>`. I think my example might be simpler if I would use not related types instead of `Set` and `Collection`, e.g. Optional.